# Why does this theorem for minimal sufficient from the "All of Statistics" textbook by Wasserman have these exponents of $n$?

Tags: sufficient-statistics

In the textbook *All of Statistics: A Concise Course in Statistical Inference* by Larry Wasserman, the definition of **minimal sufficient** is given as follows:

> **9.35 Definition.** A statistic $T$ is **minimal sufficient** if (i) it is sufficient; and (ii) it is a function of every other sufficient statistic.

It then gives the following theorem:

> **9.36 Theorem.** $T$ *is minimal sufficient if the following is true:*
> $$T(x^n) = T(y^n) \ \text{if and only if} \ x^n \leftrightarrow y^n.$$

Why does this theorem have these exponents of $n$? Having these exponents of $n$ doesn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that book, $n$ random variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$, constituting the "data set", are represented as $X^n$. Whereas realisations of those $n$ random variables $x_1, x_2, \dots , x_n$ are represented as $x^n$.

There is no exponentiation occurring.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I'm jumping through the textbook to parts of interest, rather than reading from the beginning, so I missed that.

Comment: That book can be quite terse, but appropriate if you require stats knowledge only as a pre-requisite for machine learning work. He has an accompanying publically available Youtube course here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJPW8OTey_OZk6K_9QLpguoPg_Ip3GkW_

And lecture notes on his CMU course page.